# Testing expectations on doubles in Sinatra app using spec

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

I want to verify that a method was called on a service I want to inject into a Sinatra application using rspec but I can't find an example of how this is done. Here is my spec...

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rack::Test::Methods
end

def app
  App
end

describe 'Login' do
  context 'when the user is logged out' do
    describe 'POST on /signup' do
      it 'invokes signup on the user service with the correct parameters' do
        service = double('user_service').as_null_object
        service.should_receive(:signup).with(:username => 'RobA2345')
        post '/signup'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here the App is a modular Sinatra app. I come from a .NET background and I'd use constructor injection here to solve this problem but I know this isn't the ruby way to do it.

Help, as always, is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're expecting to receive the message on a new instance of  `UserService`, there are a couple of ways to do this.  If you are using a recent version of rspec, this should work:

```
it 'invokes signup on the user service with the correct parameters' do
  UserService.any_instance.should_receive(:signup).with(:username => 'RobA2345')
  post '/signup'
end
```

Alternatively, this should work in just about any version of rspec:

```
it 'invokes signup on the user service with the correct parameters' do
  service = double('user_service').as_null_object
  UserService.stub(:new).and_return(service)
  service.should_receive(:signup).with(:username => 'RobA2345')
  post '/signup'
end
```

Comment: Yes, that does work. I can't get my head around it though, it just feels wrong but that's no doubt from my 10 years stuck in a static typed world where everything is explicit.

Thanks again, I'm sure I'll get it one day :)